# quality of polish

Tags: grammar

which is correct: (I prefer option b because it's more concise but is it correct)

a. quality of polish at End 1 (of an optical fiber)
b. polished quality at End 1 (of an optical fiber)

Comment: In technical writing, it's called the 'quality of finish', or just 'finish', or 'end surface quality'. The finish of a polished connector's endface determines the quality of its lightwave transmission.

Comment: Thank you! (comment have to be at least 15 characters)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you mean the quality of the polishing action (how well the item was polished) or the quality of the polish substance used. However if you mean either of these **only option 1 is correct.**

In option 2 "polished quality" can only refer to the attribute of being polished, or the fact that the quality of end 1 has been " polished" (artificially increased). It cannot refer to how well end 1 was polished or the polish substance.